# iOS Photo Upload From Share Extension, Respond When Upload Complete

Tags: ios, upload, share, nsurlsession

I've got a share extension in which I'm uploading a photo to my server. I process the image on device and convert it to a .jpg. I save this to a temp directory because NSURLSession can only upload from a file in the background, not NSData. The request is sent off and the share extension calls completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler:nil which terminates the extension.

The upload happens successfully which is great, however i need to delete the temp file as soon as the upload is done. I'm a bit confused on how i respond to the upload being completed. I've seen examples of implementing the NSURLSessionDelegate, but i don't know where to implement that. If i do so in my share extension code, i don't think it does anything since the share extension is terminated, then the upload happens in the background.

Any help on where i need to implement this code or a code example would be great.

Comment: can you please share your code how you have uploaded in background as I am facing problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **NSURLSession** must have a delegate assigned -preferably not the subclass of `SLComposeServiceViewController`-, that object is the one that should take care of removing those files from the shared container folder -see `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:`.

Your delegate must implement at least, `-URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` at which point it finished with one task from the session. The task is associated with one file, so you must keep track which file is associated to, in order for you to delete it.

The delegate for the session will live until the task finishes, unless iOS terminates it for some reason, then you should implement `-application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` in your **AppDelegate**, recreate the session to continue the uploading tasks and use the delegate to handle progress and completion of session.

Testing could be very tricky, so when testing, try to use big files to provoke iOS to terminate your Sharing Extension so your main app could take care, in the background, of the pending upload tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AFNetworking` works great for me Here code example below from one of my app.

```
[[[BackgroundSessionManager sharedManager] uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileUrl progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (responseObject && [responseObject[@"success"] boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"removed");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:strDestinationPath error:nil];
    }

}] resume];

[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:[self.extensionContext inputItems] completionHandler:^(BOOL expired) {

}];
```

Then you need to add this delegate to you `ApplicationDelegate`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSAssert([[BackgroundSessionManager sharedManager].session.configuration.identifier isEqualToString:identifier], @"Identifiers didn't match");
    [BackgroundSessionManager sharedManager].savedCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
}
```

You can even track progress of upload in your host app. Let me know if you need code sample for this too

Comment: Please visit for details http://muhammadzahidimran.com/2016/12/08/how-to-track-progress-of-an-upload-started-by-share-extension/

Comment: The link you shared is not working anymore, please provide the sample.